# what is the syntax for .Url in a Kendo UI treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the syntax for the .Url in a treeview.

```
root.Add().text("My node")
    .Expanted(false)
    .myCssClass("folder")
    .item(image =>
    {
        image.Add().text("theNode")
           .myCssClass("image")
           .Url();  
    });
```

Comment: So how do add a url? Url(mypage go here);